# Converting 3-SAT into k-in-4-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory

Given a 3-SAT instance. How do we convert it into:

1 in 4 SAT instance.

2 in 4 SAT instance.

each case minimizing the [number of new variables - number of new clauses] difference?

Note:  We are not adding any dummy clauses i.e. ones whose addition or removal doesn't affect the solution space of the problem to the SAT instance.

Approach: The approach I am trying is  is converting 3SAT to 1 in 3SAT as standard method: $x+y+z=1. $ $R(−x,a,b)=1;$ $R(y,b,c)=1;$ $R(−z,c,d)=1$ Then I am trying to convert this into 1 in 4 SAT adding more variables. But this seems to be failing and I am stuck.. For 2 in 4 SAT I think if I add a single variable in each clause it should work fine?

Moreover, I am unsure if this approach is optimal.

Comment: Nice question! What progress have you made in answering it?

Comment: The minimum doesn't exist, as if arbitrary large number of dummy clauses are added the difference will tend to negative infinity. Are you sure your objective function is correct?

Comment: @pcpthm I should have stated that we are not adding any dummy clauses i.e. ones whose addition or removal doesn't affect the solution space of the problem

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks. The approach I am trying is converting 3SAT to 1 in 3SAT as standard method: $x+y+z=1$
$R(-x,a,b)=1$
$R(y,b,c)=1$
$R(-z,c,d)=1$
Then I am trying to convert this into 1 in 4 SAT adding more variables. But this seems to be failing and I am stuck.. For 2 in 4 SAT I think if I add a single variable in each clause it should work fine?

Comment: Please don't add clarifications and additional information in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to include this context and make it read well for someone who encounters this for the first time.  Don't wait for someone to ask you about your progress -- instead, that should be in the question from the start.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if possible can you please comment ?